# Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb with bootstrapper project throwing error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, owin, bootstrapper, onion-architecture

Since I was trying to learn Onion Architecture, I faced an error at `bootstraper` project (Class Library Project) which includes `IOC` Configuration and a startup class. Boostrapper Startup class fired when i uninstall `Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.` But When i install this package App throws

> **For the app startup parameter value 'Onion_Demo.Bootstrapper.Startup, Onion_Demo.Bootstrapper', the
>   assembly 'Onion_Demo.Bootstrapper' was not found**

I had also declared the startup class at webConfig

```
    <appSettings>
    <add key="owin:AppStartup" value="Onion_Demo.Bootstrapper.Startup, Onion_Demo.Bootstrapper" />
  </appSettings>
```

Why does Application not able to find Startup assembly when **Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb** package is exists?

I need this package to get OwinContext to Register SignInManager using Autofac

```
builder.Register(b => HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationSignInManager>()).InstancePerRequest();
```

Since i am new to onion architecture. a little guidance is appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You should include in your question (not as a comment here, but in your question): What's the name of your assembly with the startup class in it? Is it "Onion_Demo.Bootstrapper" or is it "Onion_Demo"? Have you looked in the app bin folder to make sure it's there?

Comment: Yes AssemblyName is Onion_Demo.Bootstrapper. I figuredout the problem. thanks anyways. actually i had renamed my Projects assembly Name. the change is not reflected every place. One place it was still have old assembly name. that was arising error. my silly mistake. :P. Thank you